# revealcloud-puppet unable to load params module when trying to run install.pp

Tags: puppet

I am not really sure, what is wrong here, since i have not changed anything. But still it keeps on showing could not find class error

```
error is Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Could not find class ::copperegg::params for intel at revealcloud-puppet/manifests/init.pp on node...
```

command run was `puppet apply manifests/init.pp` , tried removing inclueds as well

repo: https://github.com/CopperEgg/revealcloud-puppet

Answer (score 0):

you cannot generally apply the main init.pp file. just make a .pp file inside examples folder and then include your main class and the puppet apply that file